# Is this example right (ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

I encountered the following problem:

> Let $I_{0}=\{f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x] \ | \ f(0)=0\}$. For any positive integer, show that there exists a sequence of ideals such that $I_0\subsetneq I_1\subsetneq I_2\subset\cdots\subsetneq I_n \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

The author (Gallian) porposes $\langle x\rangle \subset \langle x,2^n\rangle \subset \langle x,2^{n-1}\rangle\subset\cdots\subset \langle x,2\rangle$, but I thought in this one:

Define $I_j=\{f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x] \ | \ f(j)=0\}$ for $j\in \{0,1,...,n\}$. These ideals satisfies the problem, aren't they?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly true that for all $j \in \Bbb Z$ the set $I_j = \{f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid f(j) = 0 \}$ is an ideal:  $p(x), q(x) \in I_j$ implies $p(j) - q(j) = p(0) - q(0) = 0 - 0 = 0$, so $p(x) - q(x) \in I_j$, and for any $g(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ we have $g(j)p(j) = g(j) (0) = 0$, so $g(x)p(x) \in I_j$; $I_j$ thus satisfies the defining requirements to be an ideal in $\Bbb Z[x]$.  The problem which arises, however, is that these ideals *per se* do not form either an increasing or decreasing sequence:  we have in general neither $I_j \subset I_k$ nor $I_k \subset I_j$ if $j \ne k$, as may be quite simply seen by choosing $f(x) = x - j \in I_j$; then $f(x) \notin I_k$ since $f(k) = k - j \ne 0$.  A possible remedy for this obstacle is to consider, for any finite $\varnothing \ne A \subset \Bbb Z$ the ideal $I_A = \{ f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid f(a) = 0, a \in A \}$.  $I_A$ may easily be seen to be an ideal by a simple extension of the argument presented here for $I_j$; furthermore if $\varnothing \ne B \subset A$, then $I_A \subset I_B$ is also easily seen.  Taking the special case of $A_n = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n \} \subset \Bbb Z$, we then have, since $A_j \subset A_k$ for $0 \le j \le k$, that $I_{A_k} \subset I_{A_j}$; we may thus form a chain of ideals $I_n \subset I_{n - 1} \subset I_{n - 2} \subset \ldots \subset I_0$; other increasing sequences of ideals may easily be constructed by considering other finite (and probably, with some refinements, infinite) $\varnothing \ne A \subset \Bbb Z$ and subsets $\varnothing \ne B \subset A$; presumably the general notion is clear from what I have written here; e.g., if you want in increasing sequence of ideals you need an *decreasing* sequence of subsets, but they don't have to be taken from $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$ for any $n$.  Perhaps our colleague in this question, Karl Kronenfeld, was thinking along similar lines when he suggested a modification of the idea presented by the OP.

So, I hate to be the bearer of evil tidings but in fact the $I_j$ don't satisfy the requirements of the problem.

Since $\{ j \}$ is a singleton, we can't use subsets of $\{j\}$ to form larger ideals than $I_j$ as above; we need resort to some other construction.  The example given in the problem is one such.  My initial hunch is that there are others.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: This was amazing, really useful. Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: Hey!  Thanks so much for the kind words; always glad when someone appreciates my work!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Comment: Good answer. Yes, that is likely the sort of "modification" I had in mind. There is one superfluous step in your answer, that does not seem to be correct, specifically you say, "$p(x),q(x)\in I_j$ implies $p(j)-q(j)\mathbf{=p(0)-q(0)}=0-0=0$." This is incorrect, but I suspect you meant to write $(p-q)(j)=p(j)-q(j)=0-0=0$, or something equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If you make that choice of $I_j$, then you do not have the containments $I_j\subset I_{j+1}$. Indeed, $x-j$ is an element of the first but not the second.

There is a slight modification of your idea that does work though. Feel free to ask in the comments to this answer for hints.

Answer (score 1):

Ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $I_0=(x)$ correspond 1:1 to ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x) = \mathbb{Z}$. Thus we only have to find arbitrary long chains of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$, which amounts to find arbitrary long "divided by" chains of integers. For example, $(a^n)$ is such a sequence when $a>1$. The preimage in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is $(x,a^n)$.